# How to use "-join" command after a pipeline

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm training in powershell 3.0 and i'm trying to get the content of a file in bytes, sending it through a pipeline in order to join the result as by default there's one byte per line, and then send the result in a file.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
get-content 'My file' -Encoding byte | $_ -join ' ' | Out-File -path 'My result file'
```

So to summarize, does someone know how to use a `-join` after a pipeline?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't do the `-join` via the pipeline because the pipeline stage only sees one object at a time.

Instead, treat the collection returned by `get-content` as a single object and join that.

```
(get-content -path 'my file' -Encoding Byte) -join ' ' | out-file -path 'My result file';
```

Comment: If you retrieve only one column from the Select, then you can turn it into an array and feed it to the join : 
$(get-content 'My file' -Encoding byte | select-object INTERESTINGCOLUMN).INTERESTINGCOLUMN -join ' '

Answer (score 3):

Starting from PowerShell 6.2 there is cmdlet [Join-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string) which can be used in pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function to mimic the powershell 6+ functionality in lower PS versions

```
Function Join-String{
    param($delim=",")
    Begin{$temp=@()}
    Process{$temp += $_}
    End{$temp -join $delim}
}
```